# How to add margin on every page break in TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

[image: This is the sample generated pdf]

I want to add margin on top here on every page break so it won't too close to the border

Comment: Please mention what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

To add margin to the page

```
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
```

Example

```
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 20, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

set margins

```
SetTopMargin(), SetRightMargin(), SetAutoPageBreak(), SetMargins()
```

margin all sides of page
The last value if true overwrites the default page margins

```
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT,true);
```

(minimum distance between header and top page margin)

```
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER/[int $hm = 10 ]);
```

(minimum distance between footer and bottom page margin)

```
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER/[int $hm = 10 ]);
```